# Laravel 5: Output tFPDF

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5, fpdf

I want to use [tFPDF](https://github.com/DocnetUK/tfpdf) in Laravel 5.5. I added the package with composer and then I tried to output it the according to the [docs](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm) but nothing worked.

I tried to output it directly to the browser:

```
Route::get('/test',function(){
        $pdfLibrary = new tFPDF\PDF();
       $pdfLibrary->AddPage();

       $pdfLibrary->AddFont('DejaVuSansCondensed', '', 'DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf', true);
       $pdfLibrary->SetFont('DejaVuSansCondensed', '', 14);

       $pdfLibrary->Write(8, 'Hallo!');
       $pdfLibrary->output();           
});
```

but the sceen was just blank. When I tried `return $pdfLibrary->output();`
then it just returned

> %PDF-1.3 3 0 obj <> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream x�u�� �@S�)>+�p�.......

I also tried to simply save the pdf to a file, but even

```
$pdfLibrary->output('F', storage_path() . '/test.pdf');
```

did not work.

How can I save & output the pdfs created by tFPDF ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another package from [SetASign](https://github.com/Setasign/tFPDF) which is just want I wanted. Simple `tFPDF` packge with namespace support. This works out of the box and is amazing.

I would strongly recommend to use the SetASing package over the [DocNetUk](https://github.com/DocnetUK/tfpdf) package, because the DocNetUK package has just to many quirks. Here are some of the issues that I had using the DocNetUK package:

1. Output returns raw binarys, see below how to work with it
2. Renaming font names does not work.
3. method `tFPDF` was changed to `__construct`, so you have to call `parent::construct` in your constructor each time, which was necessary because of the namespacing(see [What's difference between __construct and function with same name as class has?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872915/whats-difference-between-construct-and-function-with-same-name-as-class-has))
4. The variable names have been changed randomly and there are no docs for it:

   - `$this->w` =>`$this->flt_current_width`
   - `$this->h` =>`$this->flt_current_height`

These changes make the version from DocNetUK incompatible with basically all add-ons.

---

***Outdated answer** 
I finally realized that the unofficial composer version of tFPDF changed slightly the behavior of the `output` function. The output functions just returns the pdf content, but cannot save it to a file nor render it directly in the browser.

This is how to display raw binarys as a pdf in Laravel

```
 \Response::make($this->output(), 200, ['content-type'=>'application/pdf', 'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; temp.pdf']);
```

Saving raw binaries goes like this:

```
Storage::put('file.pdf', $pdfLibrary->output());
```

or `file_put_contents` if one is not using Laravel.