# PHP calling functions from another class

Tags: php, class

Currently having problems calling functions from other `PHP classes` in the same folder. I have instantiated the class and everything, and it still doesn't work for me.
The error message I get when calling a function from the first class is:

```
method getHello() not found in class.
```

Hope anyone know how to fix this issue, believe I have done something wrong somewhere. 
Thank you very much in advance, below is the code for both `php` files.

```
<?php
class one 
{

    private $hello;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->hello = '';
    }

    public function getHello()
    {
        return $this->hello;
    }

    public function setHello($newHello)
    {
        $this->hello = $newHello;
    }
}
?>
```

and the second class

```
<?php

class two 
{

    private $sixPack;

    public function __contruct()
    {
        $this->sixPack  = new one();
    }

    public function setSixPack($newSixPack)
    {
        $this->sixPack = $newSixPack;
    }

    public function getSixPack()
    {
        return $this->sixPack;
    }

    public function access_function_one_methods()
    {
        // this is causing the problem, cannot access getHello

        $sad = $this->sixPack->getHello();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: why don't use extends

Comment: How are you calling your methods, have you perhaps used the setter of class `two` and overwritten the variable with something else?

Comment: @robert I have tried extends, it still doesn't make any difference..This is what I tried `class one extends two`

Comment: what the error message ? because i use the code but there are no error and i just add `$row=new two();`

Comment: @jeroen I have instantiated the class one.php inside the constructor two.php, so I expect it to give me complete access to all public defined methods inside one.php , I am right at that point ain't I?

Comment: Actually this is getting fun, i cant make it work lol

Comment: @robert can you see the last line of code of the second class!! So it would allow me to access getHello?, if I hover it, it would say method getHello not found in class

Comment: @Jordan Correct, your code runs just fine / without any errors when you fix the typo in the constructor and include both files: http://codepad.viper-7.com/EEgxcO

Comment: By the way, you should post the **complete** error message and not just an extract.

Comment: @Jordan i use `$two=new two();
$two->access_function_one_methods();` and here the error
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function getHello() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\New folder\submit\upload.php on line 49

Comment: @robert that's because of the typo in the constructor. Change it to __construct, and that error should disappear

Comment: @jeroen Thanks for looking into it, seemed that the typo was the issue!! Cheers guys

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, im not sure if it is what you want it, but give it a try:::

**file for class two::**

```
            private $sixPack;

            public function __construct()
            {
                include_once('/Users/hakunamatata/Desktop/one.php');
                $this->sixPack  = new one();
                print("second construct \n");
            }

            public function setSixPack($newSixPack)
            {
                $this->sixPack = $newSixPack;
            }

            public function getSixPack()
            {
                return $this->sixPack;
            }

            public function access_function_one_methods()
            {
                // this is causing the problem, cannot access getHello
                print("function calling class one \n");
                $sad = $this->sixPack->getHello();
                echo $sad;
            }
          }
        $two = new two();
        echo $two->access_function_one_methods();
?>
```

**file for class one::**

```
<?php
    class one {

                    private $hello = "Je";
                    public function __construct()
                    {
                        print("first construct \n");
                        $this->hello = 'Hello';
                    }

                    public function getHello()
                    {
                        echo "we are here \n";
                        return $this->hello;
                    }

                    public function setHello($newHello)
                    {
                        $this->hello = $newHello;
                    }
                 }

?>
```

console output:::

```
first construct 
second construct 
function calling class one 
we are here 
Hello
```

Comment: Or you could try a two file version, similar to what you currently have - http://elearningmag.info/notprathap/sample.zip

Comment: it will be same, just include_once the file

Comment: @jycr753 Thanks for the huge effort. It is now working, believe the typo was the main think to change

Answer (score 0):

is that a spello in the constructor? perhaps call it __construct()? (missing an s?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455910/what-is-the-function-construct-used-for

Comment: +1 Why is this downvoted? It could very well be the problem; if there is no constructor, the variable is not initialized as an instance of the other class.

Comment: @jycr753 the suggestion was not that a constructor is mandatory. He initializes sixpack in the constructor, so he can't have a spello in there.

Comment: @jeroen presumably because it should have been a comment, rather than an answer

Comment: @MarkParnell Okay, but then at least leave a comment that it should be improved. As it is, it (probably, judging by the error message...) solves the problem so a downvote seems unnecessary.

Comment: @MarkParnell note to self, for next time :)

Comment: @jycr753 Thanks for pointing my spelling mistake, but it isn't the problem, it makes no difference

Comment: @jeroen I agree that a comment should have been left. FWIW I didn't downvote it, just guessing what the reasoning would have been from those that did.

Comment: @MarkParnell I figured that much from your comment :-)

Comment: ha ha, cheers guys. ya, I could have written down a comment. All is well ;)

Comment: Guys the typo was the issue, got it working, thanks for your effort guys