# function declaration in a class for __constructor without the keyword public in PHP

Tags: php, constructor, declaration, keyword, public

I haven't got a better clarity after a long search about, using keyword `public` in a `__constructor` function in a PHP class.

1. People saying `__constructor` itself is public by default. So I don't have to use mention as `public`.
2. Will there be no change if I mention or don't as `public` in `public function __constructor` in PHP?
3. what is the best practice of declaring a `__constructor` in PHP? with or without the keyword `public`?
4. what are the disadvantages or issues that I will face if I don't mention the keyword `public` in-front of a `public function __constructor`?

Comment: Unless you want to use the singleton pattern.... just explicitly declare your constructor as public..... simple readability of code matters far more than saving 7 keystrokes when writing your classes. Why is debating this even a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

__constructor is a method. Visibility of methods is described in PHP Doc as:

> Class methods may be defined as public, private, or protected. Methods
>   declared without any explicit visibility keyword are defined as
>   public.

So there is no need to write 'public' visibility for public methods.

But still I prefer to write explicitly visibilities (even 'public') for methods - code is more obvious for everyone.

Answer (score 3):

[PSR-2 §4.3](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#methods) reads:

> Visibility MUST be declared on all methods.

__constructor is one of "all methods", so the rule applies.

Comment: Note that PSR-2 is a Coding Style Guide. It's a good practice to stick to a style guide, but technically there is no need to. Your answer is related to question #3.

Comment: It's not true that visibility must be declared for all methods. It's just a good practice/coding style from PSR-2

Comment: @arbogast Agree. You MUST declare it if you CHOOSE to use PSR-2 :).

Comment: @Stephan Vierkant Exactly :)

Answer (score 0):

Default is public. It's a good practice to always include it, however PHP4 supported classes without access modifiers, so it's common to see no usage of them in legacy code.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody mentions it.

```
function __constructor ()
```

Is a function that will run when the class is made. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/455929/7423021 for bigger details