# declare properties of an object out of __construct function

Tags: php

I would like to know if is a good practice to declare a property of an object like:

```
$this->name = $name;
```

out of the function `__construct`

I am trying to build an object with data from a database table. But this object will be build only if the id is registered. I know that the __construct function always return an object so I can not get a false return. So I tried the following:

```
//test.php

$mod = new item($id);
if($mod->validate()) {
$item = $mod;
}

class item {

  protected $id;
    public function __construct($id)    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

public function validate() {

        $db = new db('restaurants_items_modifiers');

        if($mod = $db->get($this->id)) {
            $this->price = $mod['price'];
            $this->name = $mod['name'];
            $this->desc = $mod['desc'];
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

This will work but is a good practice to do it like this? or I should declare everything on the `__construct` function?

Comment: One change I would make is to inject your database connection instead of making it inside the `validate()` method.

Comment: Thats fine. You can see more here in this question [What is the function __construct used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455910/what-is-the-function-construct-used-for)

Comment: Also, it might make more sense to inject the db into the `__construct($db)` and the `$id` into the `validate($id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing what you are doing is fine, but I think injecting the database into the construct and the id into the validate makes more sense. Creating a `setId()` may also be valuable:

```
class item
    {
        protected $id,
                  $db;
        # Inject the $db instead
        public function __construct(db $db)
            {
                $this->db = $db;
            }
        # Inject the id here
        public function validate($id = false)
            {
                if(!empty($id))
                    $this->id = $id;

                if($mod = $this->db->get($this->getId())) {
                    $this->price = $mod['price'];
                    $this->name = $mod['name'];
                    $this->desc = $mod['desc'];
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        # Create a method that can assign so you can reused the object
        public function setId($id)
            {
                $this->id = $id;
                # Return the object for chaining
                return $this;
            }
        # Have a method to get current id
        public function getId()
            {
                return $this->id;
            }
    }

# Create instance, inject db class
$mod = new item(new db('restaurants_items_modifiers'));
# Inject the id here
if($mod->validate($id)) {
    $item = $mod;
}
```

You can also reset the id doing this. They are essentially doing the same as injecting into the `validate()` but it depends on how much you want to be able to access `$id` down the line (maybe turning it `private` to lock it off from direct access may be required):

```
$mod->setId($id)->validate();
```

Comment: Awesome this have a lot of sense for me... I need to learn a more about this injection part but I will definitely follow your advise