# Laravel Shopping Cart Applications Failed To Display Item Total Quentity

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing shopping cart project with laravel version 6.1.0 . I want to display the total item user selected display it cart list .The problem is I was able to add the item into list but its not displaying the added list of item ..

Here is my Cart.php

```
<?php
namespace App;


class Cart
{

    public $items = null;
    public $totalQty = 0;
    public $totalPrice =0;


    public function _construct($oldCart)
    {
        if($oldCart)
        {
            $this->items = $oldCart->items;
            $this->totalQty = $oldCart->totalQty;
            $this->totalPrice = $oldCart->totalPrice;

        }

    }
    public function add($item, $id)
    { 
       $storedItem= ['qty' => 0, 'price' => $item->price,'item'=>$item];

         if($this->items){

        if(array_key_exists($id, $this->items)){

            $storedItem =$this->items[$id];
        }
    }


       $storedItem['qty']++;
       $storedItem['price'] = $item->price * $storedItem['qty'];
       $this->items[$id] = $storedItem;
       $this->totalQty++;
       $this->totalPrice += $item->price;
    }
}
```

Here is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Product;
use Session;
use App\Cart;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function getIndex(){
        $products = Product::all();
        return view('shop.index',['products' => $products]);
    }

  public function getAddToCart(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $cart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
        if(!$cart)
        {
            $cart = new Cart($cart);
        }
        $cart->add($product, $product->id);
        $request->session()->put('cart',$cart); 
        // dd($request->session()->get('cart'));
        return redirect()->route('product.index');
    }

 public function getCart()
    {
        if(!Session :: has('cart') ){
            return view ('shop.shopping-cart');
        }
        $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
        return view ('shop.shopping-cart' , ['products' => $cart->items, 'totalPrice'=>$cart->totalPrice]);
    }


}
```

Here is Shopping-cart.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')
    Laravel Shopping Cart
@endsection

@section('content')
     @if(Session::has('cart'))
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6  col-md-6  col-md-offset-3  col-sm-offset-3">
     <ul class="list-group">
     @if(!empty($products) && count($products) > 0) 
     @foreach($products as $product) 
     <li class ="list-group-item">
     <span class ="badge"> {{ $product['qty'] }}</span>
     <strong >{{ $product['item']['title']}}</strong>
     <span class ="label label-success"> {{ $product['price']}}</span>
     <div class="btn-group">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action<span class="caret"></span></button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li> <a href="#"> Reduce By 1 </a> </li>
     <li> <a href="#"> Reduce All </a> </li>
     </ul>
     </div>
     </li>
     @endforeach
     @endif
     </ul>
     </div>
     </div>

     <div class ="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
     <strong > Total : {{ $totalPrice}}</strong>
     </div>
     </div>

      <hr>

     <div class ="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Checkout</button>
     </div>
     </div>


     <div class ="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
     <strong>Total : {{$totalPrice}} </strong>
     </div>
     </div>
     <hr>
     <div class ="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
       <button type="button" class ="btn-btn-success">Checkout</button>
     </div>
     </div>

    @else
     <div class ="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
     <h2>No Items In Cart</h2>
     </div>
     </div>


     @endif
@endsection
```

Here is screen shot .
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be other issues, but `public function _construct()` should be `public function __construct()`. Notice the double-underscore.

For what it is worth, it looks like you are following the very same tutorial as this person who also had the same issue - [Quantity of shopping cart is not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57562640/quantity-of-shopping-cart-is-not-updating/57573254#57573254).